# Android studio, nothing comes in emulator on running app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run the simple "Hello World" program in Android Studio for last two days but whenever i run the app, emulator opens but app doesn't even after waiting. 
I tried a lot of things from internet but nothing worked. Please help me out or suggest some other alternative to run and test the app.

Comment: You should include the code that you have tried, we can't really give you any conclusive answers unless we see what you have tried so far and maybe then point out what you should try. On a side note, if you're just getting started on android, I would suggest you look through online tutorials, and you can even find youtube videos which will show how the basics work.

Comment: Watch basic tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: Whats your console output? Does a ADB log show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the app does not launch automatically in the emulator.

In the emulator, open the app drawer (the screen where you can see all apps in the emulator) and see if your app is in the list of installed apps.

Otherwise, you're having another issue.

Note: I suggest that you use the [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) emulator. It is far better than the default Android emulator.